# Rounding for Decimal in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am currently trying to round up the figure in my crystal report but the round function in crystal report does not change it to correct figure.

Currently i am using `crystal report 10.0.0.533`

I am trying to convert `1192.04 to 1192.05` and `1192.07 to 1192.05`.

Is this the default formula in crystal report or is there anyway i can change the formula?

Regards,

Ck

Answer (score 0):

You cannot round 1192.04 to 1192.05. If you round it, the result will be 1192. 1192.07 will be rounded to 1192.1. Rounding is removing one or more signs after the decimal.  In the new versions of Crystal you can create a function to handle this in the way you are describing it. However the only option in version 10 will be to create a UFL and add a function there.